# How to create a automatic script to copy a google analytics dashboard into a google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics

I need to generate a script which can take daily and weekly data from google analytics dashboards and then updates a google spreadsheet document in my google drive. Any hint/help?
Thanks

Comment: please share what you have done so far so it can be improved

Comment: you can find a walk though on this here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/analytics

Answer (score 0):

[Apparently Google has already build this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics/fefimfimnhjjkomigakinmjileehfopp).